# Finding Hard To Find Parts – Clutch release fork for a 1995 Geo Tracker

Tags: clutch, geo, tracker

The clutch release fork on my Tracker broke and I have not been able to find a replacement. I'm looking for help on identifying other models of cars that use the same part and, in general, ways of tracking down obscure parts.

If I knew of other cars built on the same platform, or the various names the Tracker was sold under it would give me more options going to pick-a-part yards.

Comment: Hey, Derek!  Welcome to the site.  [Questions about shopping are off-topic here.](http://meta.mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/148/discontinued-parts)  Could you rephrase your question to not be asking people to find brands for you?  I understand that that would be difficult, but it's probably the best way to get help here.

Comment: Welcome to the site. As written, this question would be likely to get flagged as "shopping advice" and closed. Perhaps you could rephrase it as "how do I find this part – or obscure parts in general." Specific questions tend to go "stale" quickly, while questions about how to purse a problem are more durable – kind of like "give a man a fish and he eats for a day, teach him to fish and he eats for a lifetime."

Comment: Ok, that's my best shot at it…

Comment: @dlu That's not bad. makes it more relevant to everyone sortof helps Derek I think it works. Lucky he is not looking for a unicorn like a working EFI computer for a late model Samurai. I have one and am contemplating on selling it for $1000.

Comment: @CcDd, thanks your answer is good. How do you know all that stuff? Ideas on where to find that kind of information would be great to include in your answer.

Comment: @dlu because I am a computer expert also know as an "it" expert so apparently I know "it" ;) but really computers and cars are actually really really similar and since I am mostly troubleshooting things like networks servers and other things I can apply those same sleuthing skills to finding problems with cars. really they are just a big computer with pistons being directed by an ecu or a cam or both. I also have a passion for cars new and old but the basic principles behind the systems are much more similar than they are different. You could say a trans is a trans is a trans same with engines

Comment: @dlu same with diffs tcases transaxles are just a mix of a few different bits hybrids are mixing a few other different bits adding computers to control injection and certain aspects of timing is not that much different than using weights and a vacuum hose with some points, just a bit more flexible. Once u have all the legos and understand what they are supposed to do u can build whatever you want. and then there is the weird legos EG. gunpowder starters, driveshaft driven cams, solenoid valves, and electro viscous differentials. but even these are pretty easy to understand minus the gunpowder

Answer (score 2):

This is the same thing as a suzuki tracker geo tracker and a chevy tracker. It has several european, asian, and south american models. It shares many parts with suzuki samurais (and their regional counterparts), some 4 cylinder early grand vitaras. The short block is also very similar, and sometimes the same, as the geo metro, chevy metro, suzuki swift, pontiac firefly both the 3cyl and 4 cylinder versions. I am not sure which years have the same or similar enough part but I hope that list gives you somewhere to search.

---

@dlu seems my comments didn't really give the information you asked for. Helps when I am not distracted by remote supports and can read the comment.

Most auto manufacturers reuse the chassis from one line of car for many different lines of car. This cuts manufacturing, testing, assembling, and repair costs down quite a bit. Manufacturers also make deals with others to assemble cars. This is how Geo formed, it was a pact between suzuki and chevy turned into a different company. As I understand it it was to get around import costs for cars assembled in japan and produced by japanese car companies. Suzuki would ship parts to canada which had lower import costs assemble them there then sell them in the US as Geo or Chevy or Pontiac. Suzuki also hat their own line too.

It is the same with lexus and toyota they are the same just get a corolla and put in lexas seats. Vw and audi, just get the passat it's cheaper. even the dodge ram 50 was just a mitsubishi mighty max with a ram badge.

most online and big chain parts stores have a database of these and which cars they go to. I do know some pick your part lots have databases of rebadged cars too. if you go in for geo metro parts it will give you the locations for the geo metros the suzuki swifts the chevy metros and the pontiac fireflys. every part on those is 100% swappable except the badges, they may also have used different paints.

Comment: I don't know how I feel about your edit to the question and subsequent answer.  But, *I do think this is valuable information to OP.* +1

Comment: @ZachMierzejewski I know it was the best I could do. At Least the answer is a bit broader. Sometimes some questions just cannot be saved. ;)